# Embed TeX as a typesetting system for an eBook reading application

Tags: programming, rendering, ebook, screen

Are there any projects or information on how to use TeX to typeset texts for screen reading? That is, I want to get the beautiful output of TeX to render in a browser-like desktop application. I want the output to be as near real-time as possible. Basically, I want a browser for TeX files that reads the files like a traditional browser reads HTML files and then renders them. The screen size should be able to dynamically resize, unlike with pre-rendered PDFs or other traditional output formats. Each resize would trigger a screen update with the new parameters (potentially overriding the file's settings).

This is more of a programming question and I'm interested in libraries that may achieve my goal rather than simple solutions such as workarounds.

Comment: Then you'd want TeX running all the time, recomputing stuff when there is a resize etc. There are some interesting thoughts about this in the article "TeX forever!" by Jonathan Fine (2005): https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb27-0/fine.pdf

Comment: See also this javascript implementation of TeX http://manuels.github.io/texlive.js/

Comment: The paragraph breaker (including hyphenation) of TeX has been implemented in JavaScript and newer HTML viewers grok OpenType and MathML - so what else do you need?

Comment: Does the [Knuth and Plass line breaking algorithm in Javascript](http://www.bramstein.com/projects/typeset/) handle things like kerning, ligatures, hyphenation and justification? Is it really comparable to the entirety of the [original TeX source code](ftp://tug.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/systems/knuth/dist/tex/tex.web)?

Comment: Do note that there are licensing issues which you should be aware of in this context. [One reason you won't find something of this kind in e.g. certain application repositories for mobile devices.]

Comment: What licensing issues are you referring to? I thought TeX is public domain.

Comment: @ReedG.Law Why would you think that? There are a few odd packages which are public domain (in countries where that is a legal possibility)  but the vast majority of it is copyright and licensed. Note, in particular, that pdfTeX is GPL. See [here](http://ctan.org/license/).

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on TeX indicates it's intended to be public domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX#License). At least the core. pdfTeX would not be necessary for a screen renderer.

Comment: Even that is not really public domain (as that entry makes clear). However, if all you want to use is Knuth's core code, things are probably relatively straightforward. If your project is that limited, that's different.

Comment: The following may also be relevant: [https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-3/tb102rishi.pdf](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-3/tb102rishi.pdf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be interested in [Kaveh's Notre Dame presentation](http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/tex-as-an-ebook-reader/).  Here is the abstract.

An important advantage of ebook readers is their ability to modify text size and page orientation, for the most comfortable reading conguration. The ebook reader has to reformat the text on the fly and with minimum delay. Current ebook readers (e.g. Stanza on the iPhone) can do this reformatting, but cannot deal with complicated text such as mathematics. We have been experimenting with using TeX as the formatting engine. Of course it can handle complex mathematics, but it also creates the best line breaks of any ebook reader, e.g. Stanza. We will report our experiments with using TeX as an ebook reader on the iPhone.

Comment: This answers the question with a good example of what I want to do. Unfortunately there is no source code and not too many details about the implementation. At least it shows that it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Your description sounds like the [WriteLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com/docs?snip_uri=http://www.texample.net/media/tikz/examples/TEX/polar-plot.tex&splash=none) project to me.

If so, you should have a look on [ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/). This is basically an open source clone of WriteLaTeX. You can also find it on [git](https://github.com/sharelatex/sharelatex).

Comment: I've tried ShareLaTeX and while it does provide rapid feedback through recompilation, it's not meant to be a eBook reader. What I want is more akin to the Kindle software, but open source (and if it doesn't exist maybe building it myself).

Answer (score 0):

I like to refer to the title of you question "Embed TeX as a typesetting system". I did not find any open source ebook reader where i could try to implement TeX. But i did transfer a special formated pdf, created by TeX to my kindle ebook reader (kindle paperwhite, 300ppi).
It looks wonderful. 
I hope someone will persuade the amazon kindle guys to implement a special tex-ebook format for their product. This would be a true unique selling point!